# My laptop starts freezing with mere 2 browsers running simultaneously. ram usage 90+%

Tags: windows, memory, freeze, virus

I am using a Lenovo G570 RAM: 4GB 1GB graphics. I am running Windows 7 64 bit

I installed a 4 bit RAM and it shows the same!

Recently my laptop starting acting weirdly. It starts to freeze even with some browsers open when I check my RAM meter... it shows 80-96% usage. I tried task manager and killing all the unwanted processes and services running, but that was of no use.

[image: System Load]

I tried scanning my computer for viruses but nothing showed up on Malware Bytes and Avast.

So, what do I do now to solve this problem other than formatting my hard drive? Is there any solution available?

[image: Memory Usage]

Comment: Open the task manager, switch to the Processes tab and list all processes by memory usage. That should show you which process is eating your RAM.

Comment: it shows me firefox and chrome at the top of the list. each taking around 600,000K of memory.
but with a ram of 4GB my laptop should be able to handle that right? @terdon

Comment: Assuming you have a 64bit system installed yes. Still, something is wrong, neither browser should be using so much RAM. Please update your question with some more information. How much RAM does your computer report? Is it different from what you know to be installed? Is this a 64bit system? Maybe a screenshot of the running processes? Do you get the same behavior if you boot in safe mode?

Comment: updated the post @terdon

Comment: If you haven't already, you should probably run [Malware Bytes](http://www.malwarebytes.org) or [SpyBot S&D](http://www.safer-networking.org/index2.html) to make sure there isn't anything else (malware/spyware/adware) messing with your system. A free online scan at [eSet](http://www.eset.com/us/online-scanner/) just to make sure its clean might be a good idea.

Comment: i think i already mentioned scanning with malware bytes! @charlieRB

Comment: Sorry, missed that line. Did you scan it in Safe Mode without being connected to a network?

Comment: yep.. i did! and scanning with the eset online scanner now! @charlieRB

Comment: check the toolbars and addins for firefox. Try starting firefox in safe mode. you can restart in Safe Mode via "Help -> Restart with Add-ons disabled..."

Comment: for chrome, start in [incognito mode](http://googlesystem.blogspot.com/2010/02/google-chrome-safe-mode.html)

Comment: that seems fine.. but my entire 4gb of ram shouldn't be eaten up by 2 browsers and its addons right?

Comment: You try running a Disk Cleanup under the Accessories-->System Tools and then do a registry cleanup with something like Powertools? http://www.macecraft.com/powertoolslite2011/

Comment: @KiranVemuri, depends - if you have driveby toolbars, it can eat your memory, even if not displayed...  http://www.freecomputermaintenance.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/firefox-toolbars.jpg

Comment: @KiranVemuri: Yes, it should be. Your issue almost certainly has nothing to do with RAM, so killing unwanted processes or services is not going to help. Almost all of your RAM *should* be used. If your computer is performing poorly, making more RAM free will most likely make it worse. Your computer *uses* RAM to make things faster. Using less RAM will make it slower. Free RAM is the RAM the computer could not use and that didn't make things any better.

Comment: oh ok! i got rid of those addons and restarted the browsers..but still the problem persists! :|

Answer (score 0):

Don't use FireFox.  In my experience, the memory leaks in FireFox have made it unusable.  If you have tabs open to pages that auto-update, like [wsj.com](http://wsj.com) or [nytimes.com](http://nytimes.com), my experience was that it only takes a day for the leaks to accumulate sufficiently to bring Windows to its knees.  (This is on Win7 x64 on a Core i7 with 10GB.)

This is where Chrome really excels.  In Chrome, each tab is a separate process, meaning the firewalling between pages effectively limits the memory leak problem.  Try switching to Chrome (or one of the other major browsers) and see if that makes your problem go away.

Comment: I am parallelly using both the browsers!
i use chrome because its fast and comfortable.. but crashes frequently.
and firefox on the other hand is a bit slow but stable.