# Internet Explorer 11 browser recently became sluggish and unresponsive in that when I entered a valid URL I would get a blank browser window

Tags: windows-7, memory, 64-bit, virus, lenovo-desktop-computer

In the last 3 days, I noticed my Internet Explorer 11 browser recently became sluggish and unresponsive in that when I entered a valid URL I would get a blank browser window each time. I have a new 64-bit Lenovo desktop computer. The other programmers in the group have the same 64-bit Lenovo desktop computer as me as well as using the same sofware tools and extension as me. Yet they do not experience this Internet Explorer 11 problem I am experiencing.  I fixed this problem temporarily by rebooting the Lenovo 64 bit desktop computer. Another problem I am encountering which the other programmers have not experienced is that Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 crashes and restarts freuently when I try to load a specific very large C++ and C# solution consising of 135 source files and 99500 lines of source code. May I ask if that is either a sympton of a computer virus infection or very high utilization(9.5 Gigabytes) of RAM memory?

Comment: How much RAM do you have in total? What's consuming the most?

Comment: @gronostaj, I have 16 Megabytes of RAM.devenv.exe and vmware-hostd.exe  are consuming the most RAM. Thank you.

Comment: Please read the following superuser.com article which discusses among other things the impact of computer viruses on my problem .http://superuser.com/questions/480449/my-laptop-starts-freezing-with-mere-2-browsers-running-simultaneously-ram-usage?rq=1.Thank you.